# R, Cumsum function on non-concatinative variable realisations

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a 306x19 data-set and I would like to use the Cumsum function on say, VarF only when VarA takes a certain value.

On a high-level description, the idea is to filter on VarA and apply a cumsum on the remaining of the dataset (VarF).

I would appreciate any pointers here guy on how to solve this.

Comment: This is trivial using subsetting ...

Comment: I would be interested to know how. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the ifelse function? Something like this should work:

```
cumsum(ifelse(VarA == value, VarF, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Indeed does work.